# How to profile racket gui code with canvas

Tags: user-interface, scheme, profiling, racket, game-development

I'm currently writing a game in Racket, using canvas. I'd really like to profile my code to help optimise it, but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it. I have a game loop controlled by a timer, which manages the object updating and calls `refresh` on the canvas (I've overridden `(on-paint)`). I've tried profiling my main file, and `(send frame show #t)`,
`(send canvas start frame)`, and my timer, but it doesn't profile the entire thing. Ideally I'd like it to profile until I close the window.

```
(define/public (game-loop dt)
  (update dt)
  (integrate dt)
  (refresh))

(define/public (start frame)
  (unless game-loop-timer
    (send frame set-canvas! this)
    (set! last-frame-time (current-inexact-milliseconds))
    (set! game-loop-timer
          (new timer% [interval frame-interval]
               [notify-callback
                 (lambda _
                   (yield)
                   (define dt (/ (- (current-inexact-milliseconds) last-frame-time) 1000.0))
                   (set! last-frame-time (current-inexact-milliseconds))
                   (send this game-loop dt))]))))
```